# http-proxy Error: Must provide a proper URL as target

Tags: node.js, http-proxy

This is my first attempt at http-proxy. I am getting the error:

`Error: Must provide a proper URL as target`

Code:

```
httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

httpProxy.createServer(function(req, res) {
  proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://127.0.0.1:10002' });
}).listen(3001);
```

I know from curl my website is running on port 10002.

What does a properly URL look like? Or is this error actually mean something completely different? Port 10002 is not accessible outside of the box, I am testing this over the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the server with the `http` module, not `http-server`.

Replace `httpProxy.createServer` with `require('http').createServer` :

```
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy')
const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({}) // I added this line to make this full snippet working

require('http').createServer(function (req, res) {
  proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://127.0.0.1:10002' })
}).listen(3001)
```